# How to I make an absolute reference using r1c1 format in VBA for Excel?

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing a macro for Excel using VBA (r1c1 format) and I want to reference a cell that is always in position E3. Is there a syntax I can use that will make an absolute reference in r1c1 format? Or is there is a way to switch to A1 and back to r1c1?

I looked everywhere and I can't find the answer...thanks in advance.

Comment: If I remember correctly, you put the number between brackets. For example, R[1]C[2] is equivalent to B2, i.e., row 1, column 2.

Answer (score 27):

If I stick `=E3` into `G5` and `=$E$3` into `G6` and then start a VB window and in the immediate window do this:

```
? ActiveSheet.Range("G5").Formula
=E3
? ActiveSheet.Range("G5").FormulaR1C1
=R[-2]C[-2]
? ActiveSheet.Range("G6").Formula
=$E$3
? ActiveSheet.Range("G6").FormulaR1C1
=R3C5
```

So the R and C make it relative to the current cell.  You need to use square brackets when the number is negative otherwise Excel thinks you are subtracting a number from an invalid cell reference.

**EDIT**: It is worth mentioning that the reference is handled differently when absolute vs. relative.

- For relative references you are counting from the cell the formula is in. `E3` is `R[-2]C[-2]` away from `G5`. i.e. 2 rows up, 2 column left.
- For absolute values you are counting from the top left corner. So `E3` is `R3C5`. i.e. 3 rows down, 5 columns over.  (thanks to @GeorgeDooling for the clarification)

Comment: Small clarification.  You are not counting from A1, you are counting off the sheet, kind of like 0,0.  So, R1C1 would be down one and over one from that 0,0 spot, ending up at Row 1, Column 1 (A).   Numbers in brackets mean "move this number of places from my current location".  Numbers without brackets mean "use this exact location."  That is why you cannot have R0C0 or R-1C-1, etc.  There is no location in Excel that is row/column zero or a negative location.

Comment: @GeorgeDooling  Thanks very much for that - I clearly didn't explain that correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes the 'Application.ConvertFormula' function is useful for going between reference styles. For example, adding this to the immediate window:

debug.print **application.ConvertFormula("=PRODUCT(O7,P$7)",xla1,xlr1c1)**

returned this:

**=PRODUCT(RC[-5],R7C[-4])**

That is a trivial example but when you have a monster formula on your hands...

Also, switching between reference styles in VBA is done via:

application.ReferenceStyle = xlA1

or

application.ReferenceStyle = xlR1C1

Answer (score 3):

The R1C1 format can be used both for absolute and relative references.
R1C1 without brackets is absolute, when you use brackets it is relative.

`R3C5` always points at `E3` no matter where you use it.
As you already know, `R[3]C[5]` always points 3 down and 5 to the right of your current location.

As George Dooling already said in one of the comments, the reason `R-3C-5` is meaningless is because you are off the sheet. The sheet starts at `R1C1` and the numbers only goes up.

As to your second question, you can use the A1 format by enclosing it with quotes. `R3C5` can be written as `"E3"` within `FormulaR1C1` without problems.

Answer (score 1):

R3C5

No brackets = absolute

Hitting f4 in the Cell window when editing a formula will toggle relative or absolute

Comment: R3C5 is an absolute reference! A relative one is r[-2]c[6]

Comment: +1 for F4.
F2 -> F4 to toggle relative/absolute address really is a nice feature!