# How to replace relative address with absolute adress in VLOOKUP?

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I have used this code for applying VLOOKUP via VBA.

```
Sub lookup()
Sheets("Sheet16").Select
Cells(1, 10).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-2], Sheet17!RC[-8]:R[20]C[-7], 2, FALSE)"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(1, 10), Cells(10, 10)), Type:=xlFillDefault
End Sub
```

But I want my output for a dynamic range of cells, So how Can I replace `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-2], Sheet17!RC[-8]:R[20]C[-7], 2, FALSE)"` with absolute addresses using `Range()` function?

Comment: check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21977655/2143262) on how to us `R1C1 syntax` for both relative and absolute references.

Comment: Perhaps you can put in the table to solve the dynamic range for the vlookup.  The table is created by `Insert` > `table`

Comment: The formula passed is just a string argument, so append the range address to it: `.Formula = "=SUM(" & Range(Cells(1, 3), Cells(1, 7)).Address & ")"`

Answer (score 2):

place the generation of the `=VLOOKUP(...)` formula in a function accepting ranges as parameters, and return the formula string, e.g.

```
Function GenLookupFormula(Arg As Range, LTab As Range, ColPar As Integer, _
                          Optional AdrAbsolute As Boolean = True) As String

    GenLookupFormula = "=VLOOKUP(" & Arg.Address(AdrAbsolute, AdrAbsolute) & "," & _
                                     LTab.Address(AdrAbsolute, AdrAbsolute) & "," & _
                                     ColPar & ",FALSE)"
End Function
```

Call this function from your main program with whatever combination of (not) selected/active ranges.

```
Sub TestGenLookup()

    ' Sheet1 active, cell A1 selected/active, relative addressing
    Selection.Formula = GenLookupFormula([A1], [A3:B5], 1, False)

    ' cell B1 in active sheet, absolute addressing - omit parameter
    ' result still in active sheet, VLOOKUP arguments in other sheets
    [B1].Formula = GenLookupFormula(Sheets(2).[A1], Sheets(3).[B3:C12], 2)

    ' any cell in any other (not active) sheet - absolute addressing using parameter
    ' mix & mingle ... all is possible
    Sheets(3).Range("D1").Formula = GenLookupFormula(Sheets(2).[A1], Sheets(1).[B3:C12], 2, True)

End Sub
```

You can choose by the last parameter whether the generator returns "A1" or "$A$1" ... you could build this out to accept 2 Boolean for row$ and col$ seperately, etc. etc.

By working with Ranges you do not need to `Select` / `Activate` anything.

Comment: I called `GenLookupFormula` using following statement but getting `1004` error `Worksheets("Sheet16").Range("L1").Formula = GenLookupFormula(Worksheets("Sheet16").Range("L1"), Worksheets("Sheet17").Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(21, 3)).Value, 2, False)`

Comment: remove the `.Value` from the 2nd parameter, you must provide a `Range` object to the function.