# Excel-how to lock down "table array" values in vlookup, columns numbered

Tags: excel, vlookup

I am using Excel 2013 at my workplace and the cell columns are **numbered** instead of alphabetized.

[image]

With that in mind, these are my **table array values** for my vlookup formula that excel automatically populated for me as I used my mouse to highlight the table area.

`Sheet1!R[2]C[-3]:R[6]C[-2]`

How do I *lock down* these values?
I tried things like

`Sheet1!$R$[2]$C$[-3]:$R$[6]$C$[-2]`
but it doesn't work.

This is my **current vlookup formula**.

`=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],Sheet1!R[2]C[-3]:R[6]C[-2],2,FALSE)`

Below is the table array source that I am trying to reference.

[image]

Please advise! Thank you!

---

**ANSWER:** Below is the formula I am using now:

`=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],Sheet1!R4C1:R8C2,2,FALSE)`

it is locked in :-)

Comment: R1C1 without brackets is absolute

Comment: Thank you @QHarr !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In R1C1 notation you miss out the square brackets for absolute or include the brackets (around the number) for relative.

References:

[R1C1, the unused Excel cell reference system](http://www.numbergrinder.com/2008/11/r1c1-the-unused-excel-cell-reference-system/)

See discussion also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21977365/how-to-i-make-an-absolute-reference-using-r1c1-format-in-vba-for-excel).

[MSDN Address Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa174749(v=office.11).aspx):

> Example The following example displays four different representations
>   of the same cell address on Sheet1. The comments in the example are
>   the addresses that will be displayed in the message boxes.
>
> ```
> Set mc = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1)
> MsgBox mc.Address()                              ' $A$1
> MsgBox mc.Address(RowAbsolute:=False)            ' $A1
> MsgBox mc.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)        ' R1C1
> MsgBox mc.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1, _
>     RowAbsolute:=False,     _
>     ColumnAbsolute:=False,  _
>     RelativeTo:=Worksheets(1).Cells(3, 3))        ' R[-2]C[-2]
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can change back to alphabetized columns by changing this setting in Excel options:

[image]